# pip install error ‘Caused by SSLError’ in linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl

I want to install the json package, but the following error occurs：

```
> Collecting json From cffi callback  0x2df5668>: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in
> wrapper
>     _lib.X509_up_ref(x509) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None,
> read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
> 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify
> failed')],)",),)': /simple/json/ From cffi callback  _verify_callback at 0x384a938>: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in
> wrapper
>     _lib.X509_up_ref(x509) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'   Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None,
> read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
> 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify
> failed')],)",),)': /simple/json/ From cffi callback  _verify_callback at 0x384ab90>: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in
> wrapper
>     _lib.X509_up_ref(x509) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'   Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None,
> read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
> 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify
> failed')],)",),)': /simple/json/ From cffi callback  _verify_callback at 0x384a8c0>: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in
> wrapper
>     _lib.X509_up_ref(x509) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'   Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None,
> read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
> 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify
> failed')],)",),)': /simple/json/ From cffi callback  _verify_callback at 0x384ae60>: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in
> wrapper
>     _lib.X509_up_ref(x509) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'   Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None,
> read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
> 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify
> failed')],)",),)': /simple/json/ From cffi callback  _verify_callback at 0x384aa28>: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in
> wrapper
>     _lib.X509_up_ref(x509) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'   Could not fetch URL
> https://pypi.org/simple/json/: There was a problem confirming the ssl
> certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url: /simple/json/ (Caused by
> SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
> 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify
> failed')],)",),)) - skipping   Could not find a version that satisfies
> the requirement json (from versions: ) No matching distribution found
> for json
```

Please help me. Thanks！

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch between Python, pyOpenSSL and OpenSSL. How did you install them?

Comment: yes, there are some version issues, I reinstalled it and it has been solved.